# Grab the parent id tag with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im grabbing a bunch of links fra a website and print them out to a list but to make the list a bit more readable i need to grab the links parent  tag but i cant figure out how to do it.

the page im grabbing from looks like this

```
<div id=bunch_of_links_1>
<a href=link 1>
<a href=link 2>
<a href=link etc> 
</div>
<div id=another_bunch_of_links_1>
<a href=another_link 1>
<a href=another_link 2>
<a href=another_link etc> 
</div>
```

all the links start with javascript so im using this to grab the links

```
links = soup.findAll(href=re.compile("javascript"))
```

and then print them all using a for loop. How should i go about getting the div id for each link and print it together with the link

EDIT - im not sure where to inset the  [(l, l.parent.get('id')) for l in links]

heres is my code

```
links = soup.findAll(href=re.compile("javascript"))

for link in links:
full_link = link.get('href')
names = link.contents[0]
print "+names+", "+full_link+"
```

I want to be able to print the Id tag together with the others

EDIT 2

I sat this into my for loop

```
 idtag = link.parent.get('id')
```

and it does not give me any errors by when i print the idtag var it return none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element in BeautifulSoup has a `.parent` attribute pointing to the parent element. Use that here:

```
[(l, l.parent.get('id')) for l in links]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div id=bunch_of_links_1>
... <a href=link 1>
... <a href=link 2>
... <a href=link etc> 
... </div>
... <div id=another_bunch_of_links_1>
... <a href=another_link 1>
... <a href=another_link 2>
... <a href=another_link etc> 
... </div>
... ''')
>>> 
>>> links = soup.find_all('a')
>>> [(l, l.parent.get('id')) for l in links]
[(<a href="link">
</a>, 'bunch_of_links_1'), (<a href="link">
</a>, 'bunch_of_links_1'), (<a etc="" href="link">
</a>, 'bunch_of_links_1'), (<a href="another_link">
</a>, 'another_bunch_of_links_1'), (<a href="another_link">
</a>, 'another_bunch_of_links_1'), (<a etc="" href="another_link">
</a>, 'another_bunch_of_links_1')]
```

Comment: @user3332151: your post has way too little context to comment on that. Bottom line: you can use `.parent` on a tag object to get the parent. How you use that in your code is up to you.